# Simple File Uploads in Meteor

Tags: javascript, file-upload, meteor

All the solutions for file uploads in meteor seem to either point to storing them in the DB, or using an external service such as S3 (which is what we've done in our last project).

BUT

is there a simple way to upload them straight to a folder on the server? (ideally without the use of autoform and the likes).

Comment: FileSystem package for CFS stores files in folders, GridFS stores in collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the [CollectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS) package, which stores files in a filesystem directory. Here is an example from the docs:

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "~/uploads"})]
});
```

Note that the path can be any filesystem path, including within the project public folder (if you are alright with the security concerns).

CollectionFS also gives you convenience methods on each file, such as generating a URL.

Comment: seems to be failing a build currently.  I suppose thats cool, but looking for a bit more of a roll your own approach.

Comment: CollectionFS is open source. Read their code and you'll figure it out or decide just to use it instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks, thats helpful, but a bit un thought out, having looked at the collectionFS source code previously, and I assume you may know as you suggest it, that its designed to provide a) a lot of options, b) adapt to multiple storage adaptors, while I absolutely agree with the sentiment, I'm after understanding, rather than flippancy.

Answer (score 1):

We use `tomi:upload-jquery`, `tomi:upload-server` packages. It is easy to use and works good.

Comment: Please take a second look at the question, for it seems to be off-topic according to the [help/on-topic]. Answering off-topic question make it look like it's okay to ask such questions - it's not. Off-topic questions might get closed and then deleted, which would nullify your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

I use ostrio:files. Despite messy docs, it is possible to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simply example from https://gist.github.com/shobhitg/5b367f01b6daf46a0287.

Step 1) Create a javascript file on your meteor's "server" folder i.e uploadImageServer.js

```
//Required packages
import fs from "fs";  //var fs = Npm.require("fs")
import os from "os";
import path from "path";

import busboy from "busboy";
var Busboy = Meteor.npmRequire('busboy');

import express  from 'express';
var app = express();

app.get(pageToListingFrom, function (req, res) {
    res.send('<html><head></head><body>\
               <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">\
                <input type="text" name="textfield"><br />\
                <input type="file" name="filefield"><br />\
                <input type="submit">\
              </form>\
            </body></html>');
  res.end();
});

// accept POST request on the homepage
var pageToListingFrom = "/";  // Page URL to listen from
app.post(pageToListingFrom, function (req, res) {
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      //saves the file to this directory
      var saveTo = path.join('D:/MeteorApp/server/', filename);
      console.log('Uploading: ' + saveTo);
      file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));
    });
    busboy.on('finish', function() {
      console.log('Upload complete');
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Connection': 'close' });
      res.end("That's all folks!");
    });
    return req.pipe(busboy);
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)
});
```

At this point, the server should have started listening to "POSTs" from your localhost's default home page, because the "var pageToListingFrom" is set to  your default homepage's url "/". You can change this to anything i.e "/home/userprofile";

Step 2) Thereafter, you can post to the listening server via a html FORM or javascrip. For example, on your "client" side's default homepage i.e userprofile.html you can use a form similar to the one below to upload to the server.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">\
      <input type="text" name="textfield">  <br>
      <input type="file" name="filefield">  <br>
      <input type="submit"> <br>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```